# How to use "Native Wifi API" Windows API functions with Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, dll, wlanapi

Im trying to use a function from Windows API on delphi, functions for Windows Wlanapi.dll (Native WIFI API)

[WlanOpenHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
DWORD WINAPI WlanOpenHandle(
  __in        DWORD dwClientVersion,
  __reserved  PVOID pReserved,
  __out       PDWORD pdwNegotiatedVersion,
  __out       PHANDLE phClientHandle
);
```

[WlanHostedNetworkQueryProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
DWORD WINAPI WlanHostedNetworkQueryProperty(
  __in        HANDLE hClientHandle,
  __in        WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_OPCODE OpCode,
  __out       PDWORD pdwDataSize,
  __out       PVOID *ppvData,
  __out       PWLAN_OPCODE_VALUE_TYPE *pWlanOpcodeValueType,
  __reserved  PVOID pvReserved
);
```

I trying to use this functions and others for hours, reading the MSDN references and others sites, but I just can't get this working.

My attempt

```
type

  TWlanOpenHandle = function(  dwClientVersion:DWORD;
                               pReserved:Pointer;
                               pdwNegotiatedVersion:PDWORD;
                               phClientHandle:PHANDLE
                            ):DWORD; stdcall;

  function apiWlanOpenHandle(  dwClientVersion:DWORD;
                               pReserved:Pointer;
                               pdwNegotiatedVersion:PDWORD;
                               phClientHandle:PHANDLE
                      ):DWORD;


implementation

function apiWlanOpenHandle ( dwClientVersion:DWORD;  pReserved:Pointer; pdwNegotiatedVersion:PDWORD; phClientHandle:PHANDLE ):DWORD;
var
  WlanOpenHandle: TWlanOpenHandle;
  DLL: Cardinal;
begin
  DLL:=LoadLibrary('Wlanapi.dll');
  WlanOpenHandle := GetProcAddress(DLL, 'WlanOpenHandle');
  if Assigned(WlanOpenHandle) then
  begin
      WlanOpenHandle(dwClientVersion, pReserved, pdwNegotiatedVersion, phClientHandle);
  end
  else begin
      ShowMessage('Function not found');
  end;
end;
```

I'm trying to translate this API, seems a lot of work, and I'm just a beginner in delphi, I read a lot of stuff on the web, how do I deal with this `OpCode` parameter, seems a C Struct with constants, and PWLAN_OPCODE_VALUE_TYPE?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439502(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? You showed code that loads a DLL function, but not the code that tries to actually use it.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel.  It's been done: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/detecting-wifi-networks-using-delphi/

Comment: @WarrenP Would be much less job, but this is outdate, the functions that I need is missing, the WlanHostedNetwork... if you know this lib of the Windows 7 or 2008 please tell me, thank you anyway.

Comment: See also: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html http://rvelthuis.de/programs/convertpack.html

Comment: In particular: your OpCode parameter is of enumerated type, but dont forget to set $MIN_ENUM_SIZE to make it occupy a full DWORD

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't actually show how you called `apiWlanOpenHandle` which would, I think, explain what the problem is. However, there's one very common mistake that is most likely what is confusing you.

Consider the C declaration of the API:

```
DWORD WINAPI WlanOpenHandle(
  __in        DWORD dwClientVersion,
  __reserved  PVOID pReserved,
  __out       PDWORD pdwNegotiatedVersion,
  __out       PHANDLE phClientHandle
);
```

The parameters that I suspect are causing you problems are the final two. Let us consider `pdwNegotiatedVersion`. This is a pointer to a `DWORD`. Because this is an out parameter you must supply a pointer to valid memory. I suspect you are just declaring a variable of type `PDWORD` and passing that.

```
var
  NegotiatedVersionPtr: PDWORD;
begin
  WlanOpenHandle(...., NegotiatedVersionPtr, ...);
```

The function `WlanOpenHandle` then de-references that pointer and tries to write to the memory. If you have not given a valid pointer then this will fail.

The naive solution is to change the calling code to look like this:

```
var
  NegotiatedVersion: DWORD;
  NegotiatedVersionPtr: PDWORD;
begin
  NegotiatedVersionPtr := @NegotiatedVersion;
  WlanOpenHandle(...., NegotiatedVersionPtr, ...);
```

This will work but there is a much cleaner way. Declare the API import like this:

```
function WlanOpenHandle(
    dwClientVersion: DWORD;
    pReserved: Pointer;
    out NegotiatedVersion: DWORD;
    out ClientHandle: THandle
): DWORD; stdcall; external 'Wlanapi.dll';
```

An `out` parameter of type `DWORD` is actually passed as a pointer to the `DWORD` that you supply as the argument to the function call. You can then change your calling code to look like this:

```
var
  ReturnValue: DWORD;
  NegotiatedVersion: DWORD;
  ClientHandle: THandle;
begin
  ReturnValue := WlanOpenHandle(2, nil, NegotiatedVersion, ClientHandle);
  if ReturnValue<>ERROR_SUCCESS then
    //respond to error
```

Note that I have also added some error checking which you really ought to be doing.

The reason that the Windows API function is declared using pointers is that the C language only supports parameter passing by value. It simply does not have pass-by-reference, i.e. `out` or `var` in Delphi terms. Languages that do support pass-by-reference should make use of them when they can.

Some Windows API functions have optional parameters declared as pointers. When this is the case passing `NULL` as the pointer is the way to signal that you do not wish to pass a parameter. Translating those APIs to Delphi is more complex. You need to implement a version using pointers to allow callers to opt-out of supplying the parameter. But it can be helpful to supply an overloaded version that uses `out` or `var` for convenience to the caller. The Delphi `Windows` unit contains many such examples.

---

As for `WlanHostedNetworkQueryProperty`, I would declare it like this:

```
const
  // WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_OPCODE constants
  wlan_hosted_network_opcode_connection_settings = 0;
  wlan_hosted_network_opcode_security_settings   = 1;
  wlan_hosted_network_opcode_station_profile     = 2;
  wlan_hosted_network_opcode_enable              = 3;

  // WLAN_OPCODE_VALUE_TYPE constants
  wlan_opcode_value_type_query_only          = 0;
  wlan_opcode_value_type_set_by_group_policy = 1;
  wlan_opcode_value_type_set_by_user         = 2;
  wlan_opcode_value_type_invalid             = 3;


function WlanHostedNetworkQueryProperty(
  hClientHandle: THandle;
  OpCode: Integer;
  out DataSize: DWORD;
  out Data: Pointer;
  out WlanOpcodeValueType: Integer;
  Reserved: Pointer
): DWORD; external 'Wlanapi.dll' delayed;
```

I have used the `delayed` facility because this is a Windows 7 and up API. You will presumably want your program to run on older versions of Windows and so delay loading is needed. For more information on delay loading in Delphi, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263693/can-delphi-only-use-a-dll-if-required/9263746#9263746), and particularly the onward links.

Note that the documentation in the MSDN topic to which you link is incorrect. The `pWlanOpcodeValueType` parameter is declared incorrectly in the MSDN topic. The correct definition, the one to be found in `wlanpi.h` is this:

```
__out    PWLAN_OPCODE_VALUE_TYPE     pWlanOpcodeValueType,
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrote this to help me http://vitim.us/test/Convert_C_to_Delphi.htm this isn't magically solving the whole thing but, just reducing my work.

Comment: I have another problem maybe you can help me, this other function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439491(v=vs.85).aspx, how do I deal with this parameter that is not a default type, this typedef C Struct. I can declare as record?

Comment: I don't see a struct, just 2 enums. Look up the values in wlanapi.h. Get the by installing Windows SDK which is essential for this kind of work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I almost translated half of the header with your help!