# How to convert a null terminated string to string?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I want to store to disk some data records. I want to have each data record of equal size so I can quickly compute and jump to a certain record.
So, I store the only string in my record as an array of chars:

```
type TFileNameIO = array[1..512] of Char;
```

After I read the string from disk, the content of my string is like this:

> c:\windows#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0 etc

I want to truncate the #0 characters, and I do something like this:

```
function GetFileName(DiskName: TFileNameIO): string;
VAR PC: PChar;
begin
 SetString(Result, PChar(@DiskName), Length(DiskName));     <----- here Result is: c:\windows#0#0#0 etc
 PC:= PChar(Result);
 Result:= WideCharToString(PC);
end;
```

There is a better way to do it?

Comment: it's been a while since I used Delphi, but I think you can do PC = @Result[1] ; WideCharToString(PC);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assign a null-terminated `PChar` directly to a `String`:

```
function GetFileName(DiskName: TFileNameIO): string;
begin
 Result := PChar(@DiskName);
end;
```

Just make sure the `TDiskName` always contains a null terminator.  If it can ever be completely full of characters without a null, you will have to do this instead:

```
function GetFileName(DiskName: TFileNameIO): string;
var
 Len, I: Integer;
begin
  Len := 0;
  For I := Low(DiskName) to High(DiskName) do
  begin
    if DiskName[I] = #0 then Break;
    Inc(Len);
  end;
  SetString(Result, PChar(@DiskName), Len);
end;
```

Comment: I get: "E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Pointer'"

Comment: I keep forgetting that Delphi's `@` operator is usually not typed, because [`{$TYPEDADDRESS}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Type-checked_pointers_(Delphi)) is OFF by default.

Comment: If I add {$TYPEDADDRESS on} other code get broken. I need probably to check the entire code to fix the places where @ is used.

Comment: The `@` is needed in this situation, but you have to make sure you are assigning a `PChar` to the `string`, so either use `{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}` with `@DiskName[1]`, or use an explicit typecast with `PChar(@DiskName)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not necessary because you can simply assign a character array to a string variable.

```
type
  TCharArray = array [1..512] of Char;
....
var
  arr: TCharArray;
  str: string;
....
arr := ...;
str := arr;
```

This results in `str` being assigned the contents of `arr`. The compiler implements this with a call to `System._UStrFromWArray` which first of all looks for a null-terminator. If it finds one, that determines the length of `str`. Otherwise, the entire contents of the array are copied, and `Length(str)=Length(arr)`.

As a broader point, I would recommend that you change to using zero-based character arrays. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types_(Delphi)#Using_Pointers.2C_Arrays.2C_and_String_Constants):

> Zero-based character arrays are compatible with PChar and PWideChar. When you use a character array in place of a pointer value, the compiler converts the array to a pointer constant whose value corresponds to the address of the first element of the array.

This makes it easier for you to interop with functions that expect `PChar` arguments.

As an aside, passing `TFileNameIO` by value is inefficient because it involves a memory copy. Pass such types by reference. For instance as a `const` parameter.

Comment: I never used a 1-based character array as a 0-based character. I would expect to write `TCharArray = array [0..511] of Char`. Does `array [1..512]` work in practice? +1

Comment: @Arnaud Thanks. The 1 based array supports assignment from character array to string. But it's not compatible with PChar. You can see from my edits that the first part was a surprise to me also. I personally would not contemplate anything other than zero based arrays.

Comment: I thought that no copy will be made for DiskName. From what I understand ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543472/delphi-passing-parameters-by-reference-or-by-value-copy ) a copy is created ONLY if I touch (write to/modify) DiskName.

Comment: That doesn't apply. In the code in the Q you pass a fixed length array by value. So a copy made and that is passed.