# possible to handle missing dll file gracefully in Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, dll

Anyone know if its possible to gracefully test for and handle a missing .dll file in a Delphi application?
For example, my code has this function declaration:

```
function KFUNC(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4: DWord): longint stdcall; external 'KL2DLL32.DLL' name '_KFUNC@16';
```

...which of course requires the dll file KL2DLL32.DLL to be found on the system, otherwise my application wont start.
Im wondering if theres some different way to code this, so my application could test for the dll file's existence, and then handle accordingly. Obviously, the goal would be have my application still start normally even if the dll file isn't there.
Thanks.

Comment: Use LoadLibrary and get the procedure address instead.

Answer (score 12):

Your import results in the function being linked using what is known as load-time or implicit linking. That is the executable contains meta data that tells the OS loader to load the DLL, and then bind to the functions that you named. If this load-time linking process fails, then the executable cannot be loaded.

You have a couple of options to avoid load-time linking, and thereby allow your program to be resilient to linking failures.

**Delay-loading the DLL**

Add the [`delayed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#External_Declarations) directive to your function import. The documentation says:

> To postpone the loading of the library that contains the function to
>   the moment the function is actually needed, append the delayed
>   directive to the imported function:
>
> ```
> function ExternalMethod(const SomeString: PChar): Integer; stdcall; 
>   external 'cstyle.dll' delayed;
> ```
>
> delayed ensures that the library that contains the imported function
>   is not loaded at application startup, but rather when the first call
>   to the function is made.

The documentation contains other useful topics that go into more detail, and cover how to handle errors:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages#Delayed_Loading
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/DelayedLoading_(Delphi)

**Explicit loading and binding to the DLL**

The `delayed` directive is merely a concise way to get the compiler to arrange explicit loading of your DLL. You can do the same yourself manually using [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) and [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx).

1. Call `LoadLibrary` to load the DLL. Either supply a full path to the DLL, or just its name. In the latter case you rely on the DLL search order to locate the DLL. The call to `LoadLibrary` yields a module handle.
2. Call `GetProcAddress` to obtain the address of a named function pointer. You must supply the module handle from step 1.
3. Call the function pointer returned from step 2.
4. When you no longer need to call the function, use `FreeLibrary` to unload the DLL.

At each step of the way you must check the function return values in case of error. How to handle errors is documented for each Win32 API function in the MSDN documentation (as linked to above). For example, if the DLL cannot be found, then `LoadLibrary` returns `0`. You must detect that and deal with the consequences accordingly.

**Discussion**

Although the `delayed` directive is very convenient, I personally have never used it. In my experience, whenever I have needed to link explicitly I've always found that I needed some extra flexibility that is not offered by `delayed`. Perhaps my needs are special, but do not be surprised if you find yourself leaning towards explicit calls to `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

As an example, just today I found myself using [`LoadLibraryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179.aspx) because I wanted to pass the `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR` flag. That sort of fine grained control is not available when you use `delayed`.

Comment: It also should be mentioned that the "delayed" directive was introduced in one of the "later" Delphi versions. It's not available up to Delphi 2007 (I don't know exactly when it was introduced).

Comment: @dummzeuch It's 2010 according to Rob. I don't really consider 2010 to be "one of the later Delphi versions" personally!

Comment: That's why I put "later" in quotes.

Answer (score 5):

When the function is declared like that, there's nothing your program can do about a missing DLL. The OS attempts to resolve the imported DLL function before any bit of your program's code begins to execute, so there's no code you can write that would do anything about it.

As of Delphi 2010, though, you can change the function's declaration to use the new *delayed loading* feature. Add the `delayed` directive to the end of the declaration:

```
function KFUNC(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4: DWord): longint stdcall;
  external 'KL2DLL32.DLL' name '_KFUNC@16' delayed;
```

If you're using an older Delphi version, then your only option is to load the DLL and the function at run time, and then handle the errors.

Another benefit of using delayed is that there are `SetDliNotifyHook2` and `SetDliFailureHook2` functions that allow you to assign hooks so you can handle run-time load notifications and failures, respectively.
So, if a given DLL, or even a given function, is not found at runtime, you can log an error, even substitute it with another DLL handle or function pointer to satisfy the load.

Both options are discussed in more detail in [another question centering on using a DLL only when required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9263693/33732).

Comment: The `delayed` feature is just a compiler/RTL wrapper for the `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` functions. Another benefit of using `delayed` is that there are `SetDliNotifyHook2()` and `SetDliFailureHook2()` functions that allow you to assign hooks so you can handle run-time load notifications and failures, respectively.  So, if a given DLL, or even a given function, is not found at runtime, you can log an error, even substitute it with another DLL handle or function pointer to satisfy the load.